# An initial-value problem (differential equation)

Tags: numerical-methods

How do we convert $y''(t) = y(t) (1-3y(t)/2)$ into first order ODE ($y$ and $y'$) given $y(0)=1$ and $y'(0)=0$ as a vector valued ODE

Answer (score 1):

Let $y = x_1$, so we have

$$y' = x_1' = x_2 \\ y'' = x_2' = y\left(1 -\dfrac{3}{2} y\right) = x_1\left(1 - \dfrac{3}{2} x_1\right)$$

Summarizing

$$ \begin{align}x_1' &= x_2 \\ x_2' &= x_1\left(1 - \dfrac{3}{2} x_1\right)\end{align}$$

Can you proceed?

Comment: No. Actually that's the point I was stuck. What should be done about the squared term?

Comment: You are done as-is. You do not have a constant matrix in this example, but you have a vector function.

Comment: Okay. And how do we go about solving it for some t ie t=0.6?

Comment: Find critical points, Jacobian, and evaluate eigenvalues of Jacobian at each critical point (there are bad cases for using lineraization - so you have to watch for those) or draw a phase portrait. You could also numerically solve to get an answer.

Comment: @Mana: by the way, the solution is given by $$y(t) = \sec ^2\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)$$ This can be used to find $y(0.6) = 1.095688915322547$.